# How to efficiently get the intersection between vector and raster in R?

Tags: r, intersection, sf, terra

What is an effective way to clip (intersect) a vector layer by raster values?

Assume we have the following two layers:

- `vec` - a large vector dataset with polygons
- `ras` - a raster dataset which works as our mask

and we want to clip the polygons to areas where the raster has a certain value (e.g. 1).

One way to achieve this in R would be something like this:

```r
ras_as_vec <- ras |>  
  terra::as.polygons() |> 
  sf::st_as_sf() |> 
  filter(value==1)

intersection <- vec |> 
  sf::st_intersection(ras_as_vec)
```

However, in this procedure we have to convert the raster to vector first and worse, we are using `st_intersection()` which is horribly slow for large vector datasets.

Is there a better (and not too complex) way to do this?

Comment: Since your clipped polygons are going to inherit the polygonal boundaries of the grid cells, I don't see any way out of having to polygonize the raster. It might be more efficient to dissolve/union the raster cell polygons so your intersection has fewer features to work with, but without some idea of your data and what's the time-limiting step its hard to guess.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two approaches that might be a bit more efficient.

Example data

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
r <- classify(r, 5) * 1
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
```

I use `subst` to set the raster values of interest to a single value, and all other values to NA. That minimizes the size of the polygons SpatVector. And I use `crop` instead of `intersect`.

```
rs <- subst(r, 1, 1, others=NA) 
p <- as.polygons(rs)

vr <- crop(v, p)
plot(vr, "NAME_2")
```

You could go the other way around, by first rasterizing. That could help if the area covered by the polygons is relatively small.

```
v$id <- 1:nrow(v)
x <- rasterize(v, r, "id")
x <- mask(x, rs)
pp <- as.polygons(x)
values(pp) <- data.frame(v)[pp$id,]

plot(pp, "NAME_2")
```

[image]